# Fastest way to build 64 bit int from four 16 bit values?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, 64-bit

Basically I'm trying to build a unique 64bit id from coordinates that I can then pull apart later on. These operations will be performed billions of times in short order, so speed is critical. Here is what I am after.  I have 4 - 32 bit integers but only the bottom 16 bits are relevant. I want to concatenate the bottom 16 bits into one 64 bit 'long' (doesn't matter if it's signed or not, since the bits are the same).  So if I have:

```
largeId = 0000 0000 0000 0000   0000 0000 1000 1000
x       = 0000 0000 0000 0000   0000 0000 1100 1100
y       = 0000 0000 0000 0000   0000 0000 1110 1110
z       = 0000 0000 0000 0000   0000 0000 1111 1111
```

it will become:

```
Id = 0000 0000 1000 1000   0000 0000 1100 1100   0000 0000 1110 1110   0000 0000 1111 1111
```

I've written a few routines that produce the desired results (i.e. builds and pulls apart) and have timed them using 500^3 iterations to try to find the fastest routine.  The routine that decodes the 64 bit number back into 4 int variables runs at about 43% of the time required to encode them.  **How can I speed up the encoding??**

**Routines:**  *(updated with variations of Paul Smiths suggestions below)*

```
        public static long GetCombinedId(int largeId, int x, int y, int z)
        {

            var _largeId = (long)largeId;
            var _x = (long)x;
            var _y = (long)y;
            var _z = (long)z;

            return (_largeId << 48) | (_x << 32) | (_y << 16) | _z;

        }

        public static long GetCombinedId2(int largeId, int x, int y, int z)
        {
            return ((long)largeId << 48) | ((long)x << 32) | ((long)y << 16) | (long)z;
        }

        public static long GetCombinedId3(int largeId, int x, int y, int z)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return ((long)(largeId << 16 | x) << 32) | (y << 16 | z );
            }

        }



        public static void GetCoordinates(long id, out int largeId, out int x, out int y, out int z)
        {

            largeId = (int)(id >> 48);

            x = (int)((id >> 32) & 0x0000_0000_0000_FFFF);
            y = (int)((id >> 16) & 0x0000_0000_0000_FFFF);
            z = (int)(id & 0x0000_0000_0000_FFFF);


        }

        public static void GetCoordinates2(long id, out int largeId, out int x, out int y, out int z)
        {

            largeId = (int)(id >> 48);

            x = (int)((id << 16 ) >> 48);
            y = (int)((id << 32 ) >> 48);
            z = (int)((id << 48 ) >> 48);

        }
```

---

*Variations of Paul Smith's technique described in answers section*

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct Mapper
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)] public Int64 Combined;
            [FieldOffset(0)] public Int16 Short0;
            [FieldOffset(2)] public Int16 Short1;
            [FieldOffset(4)] public Int16 Short2;
            [FieldOffset(6)] public Int16 Short3;
        }

        public static long GetId4(int largeId, int x, int y, int z)
        {

            Mapper mapper = new Mapper()
            {
                Short0 = (Int16)z,
                Short1 = (Int16)y,
                Short2 = (Int16)x,
                Short3 = (Int16)largeId
            };

            return mapper.Combined;

        }

        private static Mapper _mapper = new Mapper();
        public static long GetId5(int largeId, int x, int y, int z)
        {

            _mapper.Short0 = (Int16)z;
            _mapper.Short1 = (Int16)y;
            _mapper.Short2 = (Int16)x;
            _mapper.Short3 = (Int16)largeId;

            return _mapper.Combined;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct Mapper2
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)] public Int64 Combined;
            [FieldOffset(0)] public Int32 Integer0;
            [FieldOffset(4)] public Int32 Integer1;
        }

        private static Mapper2 _mapper2 = new Mapper2();
        public static long GetId6(int largeId, int x, int y, int z)
        {


            _mapper2.Integer0 = y << 16 | z;   //dangerous because we aren't checking upper bits of z
            _mapper2.Integer1 = largeId << 16 | x; //dangerous because we aren't checking upper bits of x


            return _mapper2.Combined;
        }
```

---

**Results:**

```
GetId1 = 2168ms
GetId2 = 1824ms
GetId3 = 1679ms
GetId4 = 2217ms
GetId5 = 2008ms
GetId6 = 1757ms
GetCoord1 = 785ms
GetCoord2 = 865ms
Routine1: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
Routine2: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
Routine3: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
Routine4: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
Routine5: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
Routine6: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
255, 170, 187, 204
255, 170, 187, 204
```

**Is there a better/faster way to encode the 4 integers into a 64 bit long?**

(fyi...the BitConverter class is paralyzingly slow and was removed because it isn't feasible)

Comment: In C/C++ I'd lie and cast the address of  `int64 Id64` as  `short x[4]` so I could copy instead of shifting.  Or just use memcpy.  That might or might not be faster than shifting.

Comment: If you are on .net core 3.0, see if intrinsics helps.

Comment: Is there some type that stores `largeId`, `x`, `y`, and `z` together, or where do those come from before they're passed to `GetCombinedId()`?  Are you compiling for either `Any CPU` or `x64`?

Comment: @BACON No, the values come in separately.  Only the combined ID is stored.  Right now I have it setup for any, but I may be able to restrict to x64.  I'll have to do some research.

Comment: @DaveS the answer by Paul Smith below is inline with this technique.  I tried it and after a few versions got it down to almost on par with my 3rd routine.  But not quite there.  I've updated my question with his suggestions. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: If speed is so critical, you may want to consider actual vector operations (`Vector<T>`). Parallelization of operations tends to be far more critical than optimizing roll-your-own bit bashing. Of course this may mean restructuring the rest of your logic so you don't have individual "make me a 64-bit value" calls.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Thank you for the suggestion.  Hadn't heard of intrinsics before.  Unfortunately I don't have control over the hardware that will run this, so I don't think I can rely on being able to access the hardware directly.  Thank you though.

Comment: Maybe you should look at this thing differently. If you need  64 bit ID and quickly pull coordinates apart then why not have a struct with one 64 bit ID and 4 coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 days later and a question popped into my head while taking a shower...What if the time is being eaten up by moving the return value off the local stack into the calling procedure stack?  Turns out...it was.

The new method below takes the fastest method from above (method #3) and instead of returning the variable (which causes the "stack to stack" copy), I pass in a the return value as an "out" reference.  This allows the calculation to be performed directly into the resultant variable from the calling procedure.

Doing this...I can now encode **faster** than I can decode, which was the goal all along.  Below is the new routine and speed comparisons.

```
        public static void GetId7(int largeId, int x, int y, int z, out long id)
        {

            id = ((long)(largeId << 16 | x) << 32) | (y << 16 | z);

        }
```

Speed comparisons.  **GetId7** shows the new results:

```
GetId1 = 2282ms
GetId2 = 1910ms
GetId3 = 1782ms
GetId4 = 2306ms
GetId5 = 2092ms
GetId6 = 1816ms
GetId7 = 831ms
GetCoord1 = 828ms
GetCoord2 = 930ms
Routine1: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
Routine2: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
Routine3: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
Routine4: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
Routine5: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
Routine6: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
Routine7: 71776849217913036   binary: 11111111000000001010101000000000101110110000000011001100
255, 170, 187, 204
255, 170, 187, 204
```

Not that it's needed, but I am curious if anyone can get it even faster.

Answer (score -2):

Haven't timed this but this seems to avoid shifting and masking

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Mapper
{
   [FieldOffset(0)] public UInt64 Combined;
   [FieldOffset(1)] public UInt16 Short0;
   [FieldOffset(2)] public UInt16 Short1;
   [FieldOffset(3)] public UInt16 Short2;
   [FieldOffset(4)] public UInt16 Short3;
}
```

New up a Mapper and then assign the various Shortx values.  Read back the Combined value;

```
var test = new Mapper();
test.Short0 = 1;
test.Short1 = 16;
test.Short2 = 256;
test.Short3 = 4096;
```

then `test.Combined` will be the 64 bit concatenation.

Comment: Short0 has to start at 0. Also keep in mind that they are two bytes in size, so the offset should increase by 2.

Comment: I was really hopeful for this solution as it looks slick.  However, it didn't perform quite as well.  The allocation of the structure killed your exact method.  I then made the structure a static in the class and it got faster.  I then combined bit shifting with this method and got faster still.  But my method 3 above still slightly out performed the best version of using the field offsets.  I am updating my answer with your solutions and results though. So thank you for giving me something else to check!

Comment: @Domi  thank you for the comment.  Saved me a bunch of head scratching while trying this out.

Comment: Don't the `FieldOffset` values need to be 0,0,2,4,6, respectively since each UInt16 value is 2 bytes?  When I use this code, I get values of 4097,16,0,4096 as the values for the struct members.

Comment: Relevant documentation (see the second example): [How to create a C/C++ union by using attributes (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/how-to-create-a-c-cpp-union-by-using-attributes).  Also, as stated in other comments, with the current offsets `Combined` and the `Shortx` fields will _not_ occupy the same 64-bits.

Comment: Not sure why everyone is down voting this comment.  It had some bugs, but wasn't a bad idea at all.  It just didn't quite make it in terms of performance.

Comment: @MikeS. "Not sure why everyone is down voting this comment." → "It had some bugs" is why.  Posting broken, untested code is the definition of ["incorrect content"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).  While it might have given you a good idea to explore (and it is a good idea, just a bad implementation), the person who finds this answer 2 weeks/months/years from now might not agree when they discover it doesn't work.  (But we don't even have to wait for that person to come along because we know _right now_ the code, as written, doesn't work.)